# How can I reference a specific DIV tag INSIDE an XML tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, xml

Title says it all basically.

I am using the eBay trading API and am trying to extract the text from a message sent by the user. The API somewhat unhelpfully returns a ton of HTML with the actual user message inside a div with ID `UserInputtedText`.

I am trying to get this data out using jQuery - the raw XML response is roughly in the format:

```
<XMLresponse>
    <Messages>
        <Message>
            <Text>
                "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...>\n\n\n<html ...>\n\n
                    <div id="UserInputtedText">
                        ****MESSAGE FROM USER ****
```

So I have been trying to use some variation of...

```
$xml = $.parseXML( xmlresponse )
$xml.find("Message").find('Text').find('UserInputtedText').html()
```

...but nothing seems to work.

I should perhaps note that I can get to the `Text` node itself and could almost definitely get the data out in more complicated multi-step process but I feel like there must be a simpler way.

In fact I notice now that the  node seems to have the HTML wrapped in " and also interspersed with a bunch of \n line breaks as well which seems weird to me. Can anyone shed any light on why this is?

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: I am already using jQuery's XML parsing function, whcih is how I get $xml and get to the `Text` node. I have now edited my question in case this wasn't clear. However, I have had another look, and I still don't see how to reference a div inside an XML tag from that documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse it in two steps, as the XML contains the HTML code as a value. Once you have parsed the XML, the HTML code is just text, so you can't use a selector to find elements in it.

You would create a jQuery object for the XML document to traverse it:

```
$xml = $($.parseXML(xmlresponse));
```

Get the text from the `Text` node and turn that from HTML code to elements, then you can find the element in it:

```
var html = $xml.find("Message").find('Text').text();
$(html).find('#UserInputtedText').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this might work but you can try getting the value of the  node and then do a $(val).find(yourdiv). haven't tried this though.